# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript Header Text Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, clientscript

I am using the ClientScript.registerstartup for a conformation message.when the data get saved,it shows a popup as the data has been saved sucessfully.But in that pop up,in the header it shows my localweb address as "**The page at** ** /localhost:58562/says** and below this it shows the messgae.But i need to change this header text.Is it possible to do it..??? or any other ways to do so..??

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('This Department Name already exist')", true);
```

This the code.

Thanks.

** "

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

Its a security/anti-phishing feature.

Instead you can make your own version of alert and it will do what you want. A simple modal and override the alert function call.

You can use Jquery to have your own alert boxes or confirm boxes. There are many ways but you can use this [one](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/). or [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Cheers!!!

Comment: Hi @amit kumar. 
Thanks for the reply.
Could you please tellme how to create a own alert..??

Comment: Please see the link in my answer. See the source of that page and use the jquery files there and the javascript function.

Comment: StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> MyFunction('Hello World!') </");
        cstext1.Append("script>");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", cstext1.ToString());

Make your own javascript function as per the link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a modal popup extender control with dummy target control id and call the modalpopup.Show() method where you want to show the alert.

Design the panel with header style and have your own text.